# Which is really water soluble, amylose or amylopectin？

Tags: biochemistry, erratum

In my textbook it was written that amylose is more water soluble than amylopectin. But as I searched for the reason I found a totally opposite information.
https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed052p729
Do you know which is really true?
Or this problem is more complex than I imagine?

Comment: Check quite detailed respective  Wikipedia pages, eventually their references. Amylopectin reportedly seams more soluble, being loosely packed with less hydrogen bond linking, in spite of having larger and branched molecules.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It seems many textbooks are making mistakes.

Comment: Always search for more sources when 2 different statements clash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [amylose](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amylose) and [amylopectin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amylopectin) are high molecular weight glucose polymers found in plants.

Both are insoluble in cold water, but can be made soluble through a process known as [starch gelatinization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starch_gelatinization), which is essentially a cooking process.

Some of the confusion may arise from the fact that amylose is straight chained and amylopectin is more branched.  The tight helical structure of amylose may require more extreme treatment to fully hydrate it, *but then it has a higher degree of solubility than amylopectin*.

As gelatinization techniques vary, further study of potential applications of both types of starch may help clarify which one is more desirable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. Could you explain the definition of solubility in your answer?

Comment: @satorukurita that really is the crux of the issue.  Very large polymers are not the same as simple salts.  These "gels" exist somewhere in between, depending on conditions such as temperature and whether or not they have been hydrolyzed.  They are used as thickeners in cooking.